# Failed to Fetch Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, java, ppa

so here's my problem, i update every once in a while but this time it's different, it throws me an error:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I hope someone can help, in any way thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open System Settings.
2. Click on Software Sources.
3. Remove check for the cdrom.
4. Select the Other Software tab.
5. Remove the check boxes for the sun-java PPA.

Comment: Just so you know; removing the check boxes for sun-java PPA will keep you from getting updates for Java. You may want to try to select them again later. The packages are not in the PPA right now, but they may come back later.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, i'll try it later and see if they're updated.